# Obtener datos de una tabla apartir de la llave foranea de otra

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli, web

Estoy intentando obtener el nombre de un familiar de la tabla "familiar" que tiene como llave foranea la primary key de la tabla de "usuario".
Saben en que parte tendre el error? No me muestra nada dentro del while, ni siquiera la salida del var_dump

[image: Codigo de obtencion de datos de la BD]

[image: Tablas de la BD]

Comment: Es preferible que incluyas el código como texto en vez de como imagen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no probé tu codigo pero quizas se te soluciona asi:
crea una variable luego de el fetch_array algo como asi: $id = $ids['id'];
Luego pon el nombre de esa nueva variable en el where de la consulta.
supongo que no te esta definiendo el id en ninguna variable

Comment: Normalmente se espera que cuando publicas una respuesta estés seguro de que es una solución válida. Dar una idea u orientación, como parece ser el caso, es más adecuado para un comentario a la pregunta.

Comment: oh, lo siento, desconocia ese dato, lo tendré en cuenta para el futuro @JoséCarlosPHP

Comment: La verdad es que no ibas mal encaminado, aunque no se entendía muy bien la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estás construyendo mal la consulta para obtener el nombre del familiar. Te explico.

Estás metiendo la variable `$ids` dentro de la consulta, para filtrar por `id_usuario`. Esto es sin duda porque supones que `$ids` es un entero (el `id` de `usuario`).

Sin embargo, `$ids` es un array, ya que le estás asignando el valor devuelto por `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Por tanto, para acceder al dato `id` del `usuario`, tendrás que indicar el índice del elemento correspondiente dentro de ese array. En este caso, puedes hacerlo de dos formas, ya que `mysqli_fetch_array()` retorna los valores indexados tanto numéricamente como asociativamente.

Haciéndolo por el índice numérico, como sólo se pide un campo en la consulta `select`, el índice es `0`. De forma que el valor del `id` estaría en `$ids[0]`. Quedando así:

```
$datas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre FROM familiar WHERE id_usuario = ' . (int) $ids[0] . "'");
```

Además, he casteado el dato a `int` para evitar problemas en la consulta.

Pero puede ser más claro usar el índice asociativo, que será el propio nombre del campo solicitado: `'id'`. Así:

```
$datas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre FROM familiar WHERE id_usuario = ' . (int) $ids['id'] . "'");
```

**Con eso ya te funcionaría, pero te comento más cosas:**

- Deberías comprobar que la primera consulta, con la que obtienes el `id`, se ejecuta correctamente.
- También sería bueno que comprobases si obtiene ninguno, uno, o varios resultados, y actuar consecuentemente en cada caso.
- Igualmente, podrías comprobar si la segunda consulta se ejecuta correctamente, o produce algún error (esto te hubiera chivado el problema sobre el que te estoy respondiendo).
- También actuar consecuentemente según esa segunda consulta devuelva ninguno o algún resultado.
- En el `var_dump()` has puesto doble `$$` por error, sería simple.
- Sería conveniente escapar los valores obtenidos de la base de datos cuando los muestras dentro del HTML, ya que pueden contener algún carácter que te rompa el código HTML. Puedes usar `html_entity_decode()` (investígalo un poco).